# Python - Contents of text file being posted as separate messages rather than one message using Discord.py bot

Tags: python, text-files, discord.py

I am currently attempting to post the contents of a text file to a discord channel using Discord.py

The text file contents are below:

```
Competition English Premier League - Week 35 
Competitors Wolves v Everton 
Match Date Sunday, 12th  July 
Match Time ST: 12:00 
Channels: beIN Connect MENA 
   beIN Sports MENA 11 HD 
   beIN Sports MENA 2 HD 
   Belarus 5 Internet  
   Belarus 5 TV
```

The structure of the text file above is how I am attempting to have the data from the text file outputted to discord.

Currently when I run my code (posted below) the information is correctly displayed but each line of the text file above is outputted as a separate discord message, but I require all of the content to be posted as one message.

Discordbot.py

```
import discord


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel) == "general":
            await channel.send_message(f"""Welcome to the server {member.mention}""")



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
        
    if message.content == "!test":
        with open('/home/brendan/Desktop/finaltestng.txt', 'r') as file:
            data = file.readlines()
            for line in data:
                print(line)
                await message.channel.send(line)


client.run("*******")
```

I have attempted to change the code to this:

```
   if message.content == "!test":
        with open('/home/brendan/Desktop/finaltestng.txt', 'r') as file:
            data = file.readlines()
            await message.channel.send(data)
```

With the altered code I am able to receive the complete output as one message as required but the formatting is incorrect

```
['Competition English Premier League - Week 35 \n', 'Competitors Wolves v Everton \n', 'Match Date Sunday, 12th  July \n', 'Match Time ST: 12:00 \n', 'Channels: beIN Connect MENA :tv:\n', ' \xa0 beIN Sports MENA 11 HD \n', ' \xa0 beIN Sports MENA 2 HD \n', ' \xa0 Belarus 5 Internet  \n', ' \xa0 Belarus 5 TV \n', '\n']
```

From this point I am not sure what the best way forward would be.

Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to advise or provide a solution to this issue.

Comment: working perfectly @deadshot. Feel free to answer the question and I will accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code you are sending each line in the file as new message instead what you can do is read the file once using `file.read()` and send it once.

Change this to

```
for line in data:
    print(line)
    await message.channel.send(line)
```

this

```
await message.channel.send(file.read().strip())
```

Comment: A little explanation could make this answer more useful.